# app delegate and viewDidLoad called twice

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So I have the following code in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The issue is that MainViewController's viewDidLoad is called twice if I uncomment the addSubView and makeKeyVisible below:

```
MainViewController * tabBarController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    navigationController.delegate = self;
    //[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [tabBarController release];

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

    return YES;
```

Can anyone tell me why and how to prevent this? For me it doesn't quite make sense that when you actually alloc a UIViewController it calls the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense. From UIViewController header:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *view; // The getter first invokes [self loadView] if the view hasn't been set yet. Subclasses must call super if they override the setter or getter.

- (void)viewDidLoad; // Called after the view has been loaded. For view controllers created in code, this is after -loadView. For view controllers unarchived from a nib, this is after the view is set.
```